# How to get an inner object literal value with javascript

Tags: javascript

After calling `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params))`, I get a string with the following structure:

```
{"q":"{\"email\":\"mymail@mail.com\"}","apiKey":"1234"}
```

With `console.log(req.params.q)`, I have this result: `{"email":"mymail@mail.com"}`.
But I get "undefined" if I try to view the email value with `console.log(req.params.q.email)` or `console.log(req.params.q["email"])`
What is the best approach to get that value?

Comment: `req.params.q` is a string, not an object.  Not sure why it's a string, but you'll need to do `var q = JSON.parse(req.params.q);` and then you can do `q.email`.

Comment: So before access it use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: And of course the right solution is to fix the script that generates the data, assuming you have control over it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with backslashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like req.params.q is a string: `"{\"email\":\"mymail@mail.com\"}"`.

You need to parse that json then fetch the value.

```
req = {params: {"q":"{\"email\":\"mymail@mail.com\"}","apiKey":"1234"}}
JSON.parse(req.params.q)
> Object {email: "mymail@mail.com"}
JSON.parse(req.params.q).email
> "mymail@mail.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for the check! Looks like it was swapping around for a minute

Comment: Both answers are good, thx! The backslashes should have grabbed my attention.

Answer (score 2):

You must `JSON.parse` that inner part :

```
var test = {"q":"{\"email\":\"mymail@mail.com\"}","apiKey":"1234"};
alert(JSON.parse(test.q).email);
```

alerts `mymail@mail.com`

**Why?**

Because **`test`** holds an javascript object where **`q`** holds a string, So you must parse that string if you want to extract the JSON values from that string.